# Why are a lot of new generation websites not fully SPA?

Tags: single-page-application

Its really easy to have websites fully in javascript without having to do any page reloads between urls thanks to HTML5 location and frameworks like Angular. Why do new websites not completely go with no page reloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons why someone would not want to, all of which are opinion based so there is no true correct answer to your question. Some of the reasons include

1. Not wanting to adopt new technologies.  After all the old technologies work fine.
2. Server side rendered sites typically will still mostly function with javascript disabled
3. With a SPA typically you need to use something like pre-render.io or some advanced prerender system that uses browser versus server variables to tell if you are rendering from the server or browser.
4. You are making an API
5. You are making a very simple app that does need lots of components and advanced functionality
6. SPA technology could quite frankly be considered unstable because there is no clear way to implement it perfectly with many solutions.  Older technologies may be considered more bug free like python which has been stable and bug free for over a decade.  Spa technology is being continuously developed and improved with no clear path to completion.  Many people will not invest the time in it because they do not believe it will be the web 2.0 solution.